# AWK to filter CSV files

Tags: csv, awk

I want to filter out the lines that has "synonymous" in the 3rd column. The command is like below

```
awk '$3 !~ /^synonymous/' fileCSV.csv > fileCSV2.csv
```

But the fileCSV2.csv still contains the word "synonymous" in the 3rd column. I wonder what might be wrong?

Two lines from the fileCSV.csv:

```
"exonic","LINC00115","synonymous SNV","uc010nxx.2:c.C299T:p.P100L",,"0.99",,0.56,rs3115849,,,,,,,,,,,,,chr1,762273,762273,G,A,"chr1","762273",".","G","A","30483.62","PASS","AC=24;AF=1.00;AN=24;DP=2972;FS=0.000;MLEAC=8;MLEAF=1.00;MQ0=0;VQSLOD=19.50;culprit=FS;set=Intersection","GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL","1/1:0,2:2:6:66,6,0","1/1:0,297:297:99:10476,951,0","1/1:0,304:304:99:10098,950,0","1/1:0,295:295:99:9869,929,0","1/1:0,292:292:99:8655,895,0","1/1:0,304:304:99:10006,965,0","1/1:0,179:179:99:5862,568,0","1/1:0,273:273:99:9328,851,0","1/1:0,279:279:99:7946,850,0","1/1:0,283:283:99:9214,866,0","1/1:0,8:8:21:229,21,0","1/1:0,456:456:99:16385,1285,0"    
"exonic","SAMD11","synonymous SNV","uc001abw.1:c.T1027C:p.W343R","559;Name=lod=249",,,1.00,rs6672356,1,0.916445,N,0.0,T,0.0,B,0.998605,N,4.19E-4,N,3.17,chr1,877831,877831,T,C,"chr1","877831",".","T","C","3594.56","PASS","AC=24;AF=1.00;AN=24;DP=387;FS=0.000;MLEAC=8;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;VQSLOD=15.00;culprit=DP;set=Intersection","GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL","1/1:0,3:3:9:97,9,0","1/1:0,3:3:12:113,12,0","1/1:0,64:64:99:1805,189,0","1/1:0,57:57:99:1605,168,0","1/1:0,30:30:90:768,90,0","1/1:0,69:69:99:2026,216,0","1/1:0,15:15:45:428,45,0","1/1:0,23:23:81:809,81,0","1/1:0,22:22:69:562,69,0","1/1:0,40:40:99:1142,117,0","1/1:0,3:3:9:94,9,0","1/1:0,58:58:99:14,7,0"
```

Comment: Show us a few lines from `fileCSV.csv`

Comment: It would be better if you put what's inside `fileCSV.csv` and what do you expect to be in `fileCSV2.csv`

Comment: yes, because there're words (variable) after "synonymous", but synonymous is the first word in 3rd column

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your fileCSV.csv has columns separated by `,` than you need to

```
awk -F, '$3 !~ /^synonymous/' fileCSV.csv > fileCSV2.csv
```

If `-F` does not work with your version of `awk` try

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $3 !~ /^synonymous/' fileCSV.csv > fileCSV2.csv
```

**EDIT**: you also need to take `"` into account, so use `/^"synonymous/`

Comment: it shows: awk: can't open file fileCSV.csv
 source line number 1

Comment: Oh, probably `-F` is a `gawk` extension. Updated

Comment: Check it you're in the right directory (the one with `fileCSV.csv`).

Answer (score 2):

To process csv file using awk I would prefer the following method to automatically account for quotation marks, namely preprocess with sed.

For your concrete question I would use

```
sed -e 's/^"//;s/"$//' fileCSV.csv | awk -F '"?,"?' '$3 !~ /^synonymous/'
```

If you also want to correctly process files with string fields containing quotation marks (which will be represented by double quotation marks in csv files), you need to change the sed expression the following way,

```
sed -e 's/^"//;s/"$//;s/""/"/g' fileCSV.csv | awk -F '"?,"?' '$3 !~ /^synonymous/'
```

This method has the advantage that it allows you to correctly print or process some fields using awk. For example if you want to print the first and fifth field from the filtered lines, seperated by a `:` you can now use

```
sed -e 's/^"//;s/"$//;s/""/"/g' fileCSV.csv | awk -F '"?,"?' '$3 !~ /^synonymous/ { print $1,":",$5}'
```

(If the difference between the methods is not clear to you, you can try the last awk command without the sed preprocessing)

Answer (score 0):

**`csvgrep` from csvkit**

With awk the most reliable way is to use `FPAT` as mentioned at: [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk/45420607#45420607) Unfortunately even `FPAT` can't handle literal newlines in the quotes.

Rather if you want to be saner, there are several CSV CLI tools out there. One that is really easy to install via pip (though not necessarily the fastest one because it Python based) is `csvgrep` from csvkit:

```
pip install csvkit
```

and then we can get lines not matching synonymous with:

```
csvgrep -H -i -c3 -r '^synonymous$' mytest.csv
```

explanation of the command:

- `-H`: the first line is not a header line
- `-i`: invert match
- `-c3`: operate on the third column
- `-r`: match the following regexp

Concrete examples:

```
printf '00,11,synonymous,"22,\n""33"\n44,55,notsynonymous,66\n' > nohead.csv
printf 'col1,col2,col3,col4\n00,11,synonymous,"22,\n""33"\n44,55,notsynonymous,66\n' > head.csv
```

Then:

```
csvgrep -H -i -c3 -r '^synonymous$' nohead.csv | tail -n+2
```

output:

```
44,55,notsynonymous,66
```

We pipe into `tail` because with `-H` it adds a dummy header which is annoying:

```
a,b,c,d
44,55,notsynonymous,66
```

it is annoying but I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Without `-i` we select `synonymous` instead:

```
csvgrep -H -c3 -r '^synonymous$' nohead.csv | tail -n+2
```

output:

```
00,11,synonymous,"22,
""33"
```

And for when we have a header we can use the column name:

```
csvgrep -c col3 -r '^synonymous$' head.csv
```

output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
00,11,synonymous,"22,
""33"
```

Tested on csvkit 1.0.7, Ubuntu 23.04.