# What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?

Tags: csv, awk

The intent of this question is to provide a canonical answer.

Given a CSV as might be generated by Excel or other tools with embedded newlines and/or double quotes and/or commas in fields, and empty fields like:

```
$ cat file.csv
"rec1, fld1",,"rec1"",""fld3.1
"",
fld3.2","rec1
fld4"
"rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2","rec2 fld2.1""fld2.2""fld2.3","",rec2 fld4
"""""","""rec3,fld2""",
```

What's the most robust way efficiently using awk to identify the separate records and fields:

```
Record 1:
    $1=<rec1, fld1>
    $2=<>
    $3=<rec1","fld3.1
",
fld3.2>
    $4=<rec1
fld4>
----
Record 2:
    $1=<rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2>
    $2=<rec2 fld2.1"fld2.2"fld2.3>
    $3=<>
    $4=<rec2 fld4>
----
Record 3:
    $1=<"">
    $2=<"rec3,fld2">
    $3=<>
----
```

so it can be used as those records and fields internally by the rest of the awk script.

A valid CSV would be one that conforms to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) or can be generated by MS-Excel.

The solution must tolerate the end of record just being LF (`\n`) as is typical for UNIX files rather than CRLF (`\r\n`) as that standard requires and Excel or other Windows tools would generate. It will also tolerate unquoted fields mixed with quoted fields. It will specifically not need to tolerate escaping `"`s with a preceding backslash (i.e. `\"` instead of `""`) as some other CSV formats allow - if you have that then adding a `gsub(/\\"/,"\"\"")` up front would handle it and trying to handle both escaping mechanisms automatically in one script would make the script unnecessarily fragile and complicated.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560393/bash-shell-scripting-csv-parsing

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205431/parse-a-csv-using-awk-and-ignoring-commas-inside-a-field

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Updated to reflect the [release of GNU awk 5.3](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.awk/c/zQtAPIbzFrc/m/H0uNeJG8BAAJ) for the [`--csv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Comma-Separated-Fields) option to enable CSV parsing (also available now in Kernighan's [One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) so I expect the `gawk 5.3` scripts below will also work there but I don't have a copy of `onetrueawk` to test with):

**If you have GNU awk 5.3 or later for [`--csv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Comma-Separated-Fields)** (or equivalently `-k`) and you neither have to retain the input quotes nor have a separator other than `,`:

`--csv` reads multi-line records and splits quoted fields correctly.

```
awk --csv -v OFS=',' '
    {
        printf "Record %d:\n", NR
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "    $%d=<%s>\n", i, $i
        }
        print "----"
    }
'
```

This automatically reads multi-line records that have newlines within quoted fields but you can **only** use `,` as a separator and `"` as the field-surrounding quote with `--csv`.

Note that `--csv` automatically strips quotes from around quoted fields and converts escaped quotes (`""`) within fields to single quotes (`"`). That is usually the desired behavior but if it's not what you want there are alternatives below.

**If you have GNU awk 4.0 or later for [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content):**

`FPAT` splits quoted fields correctly but does not automatically read multi-line records so you need to implement that part.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' '
    function readRec(      line,rec) {
        # Keep reading lines until we have an even number of quotes
        # as an incomplete record will have an uneven number.
        rec = $0
        while ( (gsub(/"/,"&",rec) % 2) && ((getline line) > 0) ) {
            rec = rec RS line
            NR--
            FNR--
        }
        $0 = rec
    }

    {
        readRec()
        printf "Record %d:\n", ++recNr
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            # Convert <"foo"> to <foo> and <"foo""bar"> to <foo"bar>
            gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $i)
            gsub(/""/, "\"", $i)

            printf "    $%d=<%s>\n", i, $i
        }
        print "----"
    }
'
```

You can use any character as a separator and any character as the field-surrounding quote with `FPAT` since you define those and write some of the code to parse the input for them but you have to write your own code to read multi-line records.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#More-CSV for info on the `FPAT` setting I use above. That would also be a good choice if you have gawk 5.3+ but `--csv` isn't a good option for you, e.g. because you need to retain quotes or use a different separator character.

**If you have any modern* awk:**

With neither `--csv` nor `FPAT` you have to implement both reading multi-line fields and splitting quoted fields correctly.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '
    function readRec(      line,rec) {
        # Keep reading lines until we have an even number of quotes
        # as an incomplete record will have an uneven number.
        rec = $0
        while ( (gsub(/"/,"&",rec) % 2) && ((getline line) > 0) ) {
            rec = rec RS line
            NR--
            FNR--
        }
        $0 = rec
    }

    function splitRec(      orig,tail,fpat,fldNr) {
        # You must call this function every time you change $0 to
        # repopulate the fields taking quoted fields into account.
    
        orig = tail = $0
        $0 = ""
        fpat = "([^" FS "]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"
        while ( (tail != "") && match(tail,fpat) ) {
            $(++fldNr) = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
        }
    
        # If the original $0 ended with a null field we would exit the
        # loop above before handling it so handle it here.
        if ( orig ~ ("["FS"]$") ) {
            $(++fldNr) = ""
        }
    }
    
    {
        readRec()
        splitRec()
        printf "Record %d:\n", NR
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            # Convert <"foo"> to <foo> and <"foo""bar"> to <foo"bar>
            gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $i)
            gsub(/""/, "\"", $i)
    
            printf "    $%d=<%s>\n", i, $i
        }
        print "----"
    }
'
```

You can use any character as a separator and any character as the field-surrounding quote with the the above "any modern* awk" solution since you define those and write all of the code to parse the input for them and you also have to write your own code to read multi-line records.

Decrementing `NR` and `FNR` above is done because `getline` increments them every time it reads a line to add to the record. Changing the value of `NR` and `FNR` is undefined behavior per POSIX, though, so if your awk doesn't support that then just create and use your own `Fnr` and `Nr` or similarly named variables to keep track of record numbers.

---

***Some related information/scripts:***

**To add quotes to output fields when using `--csv`**

By default given this input:

```
$ cat file
foo,"field 2 ""contains"" quotes, and comma",bar
```

you might expect this script which prints the first 2 fields:

```
awk --csv -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}' file
```

to produce this output:

```
foo,"field 2 ""contains"" quotes, and comma"
```

but it doesn't, it produces this output instead:

```
$ awk --csv -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}' file
foo,field 2 "contains" quotes, and comma
```

Note that field 2 from the input has now, probably undesirably, become 2 separate fields in the output as it's surrounding quotes were stripped so the `,` that was inside of those quotes is now a separator.

If you want the output fields quoted then you need to manually add the quotes by doing whichever of the following makes sense for your application:

To add quotes around a field or any other string:

```
enquote(str) {
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"",str)
    return "\"" str "\""
}
```

To add quotes around all fields:

```
enquote_all() {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        $i = enquote($i)
    }
}
```

To add quotes around only the fields that NEED to be quoted:

```
enquote_needed() {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i ~ /[\n,"]/ ) {
            $i = enquote($i)
        }
    }
}
```

**To retain the quotes that were present in the input**

You need to use `readRec()` and/or `splitRec()` above, depending if you're using `--csv` or `FPAT` or neither. There is no way to make `--csv` not remove quotes when populating fields and you cannot use `--csv` and `FPAT`, `FS` or `FIELDWIDTHS` together as using `--csv` tells awk to ignore those other variables that otherwise control field splitting.

So, assuming your fields retain their original quotes, you can do the following or similar to conditionally reproduce those quotes in the output (and to also add new quotes if the field would otherwise be invalid CSV):

```
function dequote_cond(fldNr,    had_quotes) {
    had_quotes = ( gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$fldNr) || gsub(/""/,"\"",$fldNr) )
    return had_quotes+0
}
function enquote_cond(fldNr,had_quotes,    got_quotes) {
    if ( had_quotes || ($fldNr ~ /[\n",]/) ) {
        gsub(/"/,"\"\",$fldNr)
        $fldNr = "\"" $fldNr "\""
        got_quotes = 1
    }
    return got_quotes+0     # probably unused, for symmetry with dequote_cond() 
}
...
q = dequote_cond(i)
$i = new value
enquote_cond(i,q)
```

**To print fields with quotes removed if your CSV cannot contain newlines:**

- With GNU awk 5.3 or later for `--csv`: Exactly the same as above
  `--csv` case that includes newlines in fields.
- With GNU awk 4.0 or later for `FPAT`: The same as above `FPAT` case
  that includes newlines in fields except you don't need to define or
  call `readRec()`.
- With any modern* awk: The same as above "any modern* awk"" case that includes newlines in fields except you don't need to define or call `readRec()`.

If you **don't** want the quotes removed then, if using `--csv` add quotes as described above, and if you're using either of the other solutions then don't remove the quotes with the 2 `gsub()`s.

**To convert newlines within fields to blanks and commas within fields to semi-colons**

If all you actually want to do is convert your CSV to a simpler version with individual lines by, say, replacing newlines with blanks and commas with semi-colons inside quoted fields (and have quoted fields in the output) then:

With GNU awk 3.0 or later for `RT`:

```
awk -v RS='"([^"]|"")*"' -v ORS= '{
    gsub(/\n/," ",RT)
    gsub(/,/,";",RT)
    print $0 RT
}'
```

Otherwise: use one of the solutions discussed earlier that use `readRec()` and add the 2 `gsub()s` above in a loop on the fields.

**If you want a CSV but have a different character than `,` as your delimiter.**

If you have a CSV-like file that uses tabs or `;`s or `|`s or some other character to separate fields then you can do the following using any awk to convert your file to CSV:

```
$ cat changeSeps.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\""

    if ( (old == "") || (new == "") ) {
        printf "Error: old=\047%s\047 and/or new=\047%s\047 separator string missing.\n", old, new |"cat>&2"
        printf "Usage: awk -v old=\047;\047 -v new=\047,\047 -f changeSeps.awk infile [> outfile]\n" |"cat>&2"
        err = 1
        exit
    }

    sanitized_old = old
    sanitized_new = new

    # Ensure all regexp and replacement chars get treated as literal
    gsub(/[^^\\]/,"[&]",sanitized_old)  # regexp: char other than ^ or \ -> [char]
    gsub(/\\/,"\\\\",sanitized_old)     # regexp: \ -> \\
    gsub(/\^/,"\\^",sanitized_old)      # regexp: ^ -> \^
    gsub(/[&]/,"\\\\&",sanitized_new)   # replacement: & -> \\&
}
{
    $0 = prev ors $0
    prev = $0
    ors = ORS
}
NF%2 {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
        cnt += gsub(sanitized_old,sanitized_new,$i)
    }
    print
    prev = ors = ""
}
END {
    if ( !err ) {
        printf "Converted %d \047%s\047 field separators to \047%s\047s.\n", cnt+0, old, new |"cat>&2"
    }
    exit err
}
```

which you'd call as, for example to change `;`-separated to `,`-separated format:

```
awk -v old=';' -v new=',' -f changeSeps.awk file
```

**If you have DOS/Windows line endings**

With Windows `\r\n` line endings, e.g. as in a CSV exported from Excel, processing can be simpler than the above as the "newlines" within each field can often actually just be line feeds (i.e. `\n`s) and so you can set `RS="\r\n"` (using GNU awk for multi-char RS) and then the `\n`s within fields will not be treated as line endings so all you additionally need to parse CSV is to set `FPAT`. SOmetimes, though, the underlying C primitives will not pass along the `\r` to gawk and you'd need to set [`-v BINDMODE=3`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#PC-Using) on the gawk command line to see them.

**Other notes**

*I say "modern awk" above because there's apparently extremely old (i.e. circa 2000) versions of `tawk` and `mawk1` still around which have bugs in their `gsub()` implementation such that `gsub(/^"|"$/,"",fldStr)` would not remove the start/end `"`s from `fldStr`. If you're using one of those then **get a new awk, preferably `gawk`,** as there could be other issues with them too but if that's not an option then I expect you can work around that particular bug by changing this:

```
gsub(/^"|"$/,"",fldStr)
```

to this:

```
sub(/^"/,"",fldStr)
sub(/"$/,"",fldStr)
```

Thanks to the following people for identifying and suggesting solutions to the stated issues with the original version of this answer:

1. [@mosvy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10306503/mosvy) for escaped double quotes within fields.
2. [@datatraveller1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18135892/datatraveller1) for multiple contiguous pairs of escaped quotes in a field and null fields at the end of records.

Related: also see [How do I use awk under cygwin to print fields from an excel spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38805123/1745001) for how to generate CSVs from Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I was about to edit myself but upon second reading, I realized you weren't trying to say that gawk led and awk followed, and couldn't really come up with a more natural way of saying it myself either, so I will just delete my comment instead.

Answer (score 12):

An improvement upon @EdMorton's `FPAT` solution, which should be able to handle double-quotes(`"`) escaped by doubling (`""` -- as allowed by the CSV [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)).

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("[^"]*")+' ...
```

This STILL

1. isn't able to handle newlines inside quoted fields, which are perfectly legit in standard CSV files.
2. assumes **GNU awk** (`gawk`), a standard awk won't do.

Example:

```
$ echo 'a,,"","y""ck","""x,y,z"," ",12' |
gawk -v OFS='|' -v FPAT='[^,]*|("[^"]*")+' '{$1=$1}1'
a||""|"y""ck"|"""x,y,z"|" "|12

$ echo 'a,,"","y""ck","""x,y,z"," ",12' |
gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("[^"]*")+' '{
  for(i=1; i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/"/){ $i = substr($i, 2, length($i)-2); gsub(/""/,"\"", $i) }
    print "<"$i">"
  }
}'
<a>
<>
<>
<y"ck>
<"x,y,z>
< >
<12>
```

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, including this way of defining `FPAT`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [csvquote](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote) is for - it makes things simple for awk and other command line data processing tools.

Some things are difficult to express in awk. Instead of running a single awk command and trying to get awk to handle the quoted fields with embedded commas and newlines, the data gets prepared for awk by csvquote, so that awk can always interpret the commas and newlines it finds as field separators and record separators. This makes the awk part of the pipeline simpler. Once awk is done with the data, it goes back through `csvquote -u` to restore the embedded commas and newlines inside quoted fields.

```
csvquote file.csv | awk -f my_awk_script | csvquote -u
```

EDIT:

For a complete description on `csvquote`, see: [How it works](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote#how-it-works). this also explains the `` characters which are shown in places where there was a carriage return.

```
csvquote file.csv | awk -f decsv.awk | csvquote -u
```

(for the source of `decsv.awk` see answer from Ed Morton )
output:

```
Record 1:
    $1=<rec1 fld1>
    $2=<>
    $3=<rec1","fld3.1",
fld3.2>
    $4=<rec1
fld4>
----
Record 2:
    $1=<rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2>
    $2=<rec2 fld2.1"fld2.2"fld2.3>
    $3=<>
    $4=<rec2 fld4>
----
Record 3:
    $1=<"">
    $2=<"rec3fld2">
    $3=<>
----
```

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit) a really useful toolkit to handle with csv files in command line.

```sh
line='test,t2,t3,"t5,"'
echo $line | csvcut -c 4
"t5,"
```

```sh
echo 'foo,"field,""with"",commas",bar'  | csvcut -c 3
bar
```

It also contains `csvstat`, `csvstack` etc. tools which are also very handy.

```sh
cat file.csv
"rec1, fld1",,"rec1"",""fld3.1
"",
fld3.2","rec1
fld4"
"rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2","rec2 fld2.1""fld2.2""fld2.3","",rec2 fld4
"""""","""rec3,fld2""",
```

```sh
csvcut -c 1 file.csv

"rec1, fld1"
"rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2"
""""""

csvcut -c 3 file.csv
"rec1"",""fld3.1
"",
fld3.2"
""
""
```

Comment: This question is about how to process CSVs with awk, there's lots of ways with lots of other tools to handle CSVs. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As [announced](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.awk/c/l5qjXZfOnhk) by Arnold Robbins, starting in version 5.3.0 GNU awk will have builtin support for CSV files including the edge cases discussed in this thread via the option `--csv`. The implementation follows Brian Kernighan's [One True AWK](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk).

Using the script provided in [@Ben Hoyt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68707/ben-hoyt)'s answer:

```
$ cat records.awk
{
    printf "Record %d:\n", NR
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "    $%d=<%s>\n", i, $i
    print "----"
}
```

the program produces the desired output after the call:

```
gawk --csv -f records.awk file.csv
```

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Awk (gawk) actually provides extensions, one of which being [csv processing](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/csv/gawk-csv.html), which *is* the most robust way to do so with *gawk* in my opinion. The extension takes care of many gotchas and parses the csv for you.

Assuming that extension is installed, you can use awk to show all lines where a specific csv field matches `123`.

Assuming `test.csv` contains the following:

```
Name,Phone
"Woo, John",425-555-1212
"James T. Kirk",123
```

The following will print all lines where the `Phone` (aka the second field) is equal to `123`:

```bash
gawk -l csv 'csvsplit($0,a) && a[2] == 123 {print a[1]}'
```

The output is:

```
James T. Kirk
```

How does it work?

- `-l csv` asks gawk to load the `csv` extension by looking for it in `$AWKLIBPATH`;
- `csvsplit($0, a)` splits the current line, and stores each field into a new array named `a`
- `&& a[2] == 123` checks that the second field is `123`
- if both conditions are true, it `{ print a[1] }`, aka prints first csv field of the line.

Comment: The library described above was never released and instead in version 5.3 gawk introduced a `--csv` option. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of the common AWK interpreters (Gawk, onetrueawk, mawk), the other solutions are your best bet. However, if you're able to use a different interpreter, frawk and GoAWK have proper CSV support built-in.

[frawk](https://github.com/ezrosent/frawk) is a very fast AWK implementation written in Rust. Use `-i csv` to process input in CSV mode. Note that frawk is not quite POSIX compatible (see [differences](https://github.com/ezrosent/frawk/blob/master/info/overview.md#what-is-different)).

[GoAWK](https://github.com/benhoyt/goawk) is a POSIX-compatible AWK implementation written in Go. Also supports `-i csv` mode, as well as `-H` (parse header row) with `@"named_field"` syntax ([read more](https://benhoyt.com/writings/goawk-csv/)). *Disclaimer: I'm the author of GoAWK.*

With `file.csv` as per the question, you can simply use an AWK script with a regular `for` loop over the fields as follows:

```
$ cat records.awk
{
    printf "Record %d:\n", NR
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "    $%d=<%s>\n", i, $i
    print "----"
}
```

Then use either `frawk -i csv` or `goawk -i csv` to get the expected output. For example:

```
$ frawk -i csv -f records.awk file.csv
Record 1:
    $1=<rec1, fld1>
    $2=<>
    $3=<rec1","fld3.1
",
fld3.2>
    $4=<rec1
fld4>
----
Record 2:
    $1=<rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2>
    $2=<rec2 fld2.1"fld2.2"fld2.3>
    $3=<>
    $4=<rec2 fld4>
----
Record 3:
    $1=<"">
    $2=<"rec3,fld2">
    $3=<>
----

$ goawk -i csv -f records.awk file.csv 
Record 1:
... same as above ...
----
```

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get into complicated CSV, it is really easier to use a proper parser. While the `gawk` scripts using `FPAT` are amazing, they are not a complete RFC 4180 solution.

My goto for CSV parsing at the command prompt is Ruby. There are others (Perl, Python are wonderful) but Ruby is closest to Awk syntax.

Here is a minimal Ruby to parse your example:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
CSV.parse($<.read).
    each_with_index{|record, idx| 
        puts "Record #{idx+1}:"
        record.each_with_index{|fld, i| 
            puts "\t$#{i+1}=<#{fld}>"
        }
        puts "----"
    }

' file
```

With your example input, prints:

```
Record 1:
    $1=<rec1, fld1>
    $2=<>
    $3=<rec1","fld3.1
",
fld3.2>
    $4=<rec1
fld4>
----
Record 2:
    $1=<rec2, fld1.1

fld1.2>
    $2=<rec2 fld2.1"fld2.2"fld2.3>
    $3=<>
    $4=<rec2 fld4>
----
Record 3:
    $1=<"">
    $2=<"rec3,fld2">
    $3=<>
----
```

Note that nothing at all needed to be done to the records or fields since they were properly parsed with default values. (Well, you need `+1` since Ruby arrays are `0` based.)

Comment: This question is about how to process CSVs with awk, there's lots of ways with lots of other tools to handle CSVs. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/1745001) to include and explain use/pros/cons of `gawk --csv` as well as various other awk possibilities now, thanks.